# Fade animation on banner failing, mostly on Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, animation

On chrome, when switching into the tab/window during the animation, the animation will be interrupted, whiting out the banner until the next timed frame switch. This only happens on Chrome.

On any browser, rapidly switching between frames will cause the same type of failure.

Additionally it seems to get stuck on frame 2 on occasion (mostly just in chrome)

I have tried locking the animation while it is proceeding, switching click-event switching to be a timed event with a delay of 0.5s (the animation's length)... This for the most part fixes the 2nd issue but is not ideal (the delay is infuriating).

Is this a Chrome bug? Or much more likely, what am I doing wrong?

This is the function that activates a new banner every 5 seconds. Originally, all banners were faded out first, but I tried this in an attempt to fix what I originally thought may have been the issue.

```
function activate_banner(banner_id) {
    fadeIn(banners[banner_id]);
    for (var i = 0; i < banner_iter.length; i++)
    if (banner_ids[i] != banner_id) fadeOut(banners[banner_iter[i]]);
}
```

fading in is very straightforward:

```
el.style.display = "";
el.style.zIndex = "1";
el.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s linear 0s";
el.style.opacity = 1;
```

Fading out uses event listeners to hide the frame's div:

```
if (el.style.display == "none") return;

el.style.zIndex = "99";
el.style.transition = "opacity 0.5s linear 0s";
el.style.opacity = 0;

var transitionEvent = whichTransitionEvent(el);
if (el.addEventListener) transitionEvent && el.addEventListener(transitionEvent, function () {
    el.style.display = "none";
});
else transitionEvent && el.attachEvent(transitionEvent, function () {
    el.style.display = "none";
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1keo62ca/8/